# How to link to a specific shape inside SVG image

Tags: html, svg

I have an HTML page that contains a large in-line SVG image.  The image is far too large to be drawn in a standard viewport, so the browser window has horizontal and vertical scroll bars displayed.  The image contains many rectangles.

I would like to be able to link *into* this page so that a specified rectangle is scrolled into view, much the same way a particular location can be linked inside an HTML document.  I would, for instance, like to link to `https://blahblah/page_with_image#RECT950` and know that the page would appear with RECT950 visible in the viewport.

(NOTE: I'm not trying to place links in the SVG, I'm trying to link from outside the page to a specific anchor location inside the SVG)

I've tried the following inside my `<svg>` tag:

```
<a id="RECT950"></a><rect x="1110" y="1810" width="230" height="230" style="fill: white; stroke-width: 4; stroke: black"/>
```

and

```
<a id="RECT950"><rect x="1110" y="1810" width="230" height="230" style="fill: white; stroke-width: 4; stroke: black"/></a>
```

Can this be done, and if so how?

Comment: I know this seems obvious, but why can't you split the SVG into its component parts?

Comment: It's a giant graph structure with lines connecting the rectangles-- so one complete figure, not little rectangular figures on a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

If you link to an HTML page and the HTML page contains an SVG and the link contains a fragment (`#ANCHOR_NAME`) and the specified anchor is an element inside the SVG, then the anchor will not be found.  There does not appear to be a way around this.

Instead, you must add some javascript in the `window.onload` function to use the `scrollIntoView()` function to scroll the page.  In my example I also had to add a brief delay before calling `scrollIntoView`.

There is a separate and distinct ability to specify a fragment in a URL that addresses and SVG image directly (not an image embedded in HTML).  This "fragment language" can load a "view" of the SVG image but this requires the SVG to be inside a viewbox.  This fragment language does not help to solve the problem that I had.